# How can I log async errors to the console instead of showing an ErrorWidget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does flutter display the exception in asynchronous code within StreamBuilder as a Container() widget instead of printing it to the console?

I tried already following but it does nothing.

```
void main() {      

  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    print('error');
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
  };
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a StreamBuilder you have to check the snapshot for errors if the asynchronous code throws an exception (snapshot.hasError).If you don't do that, the StreamBuilder will display the error as a widget.

Solution:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Todo>>(
      stream: todoService.todoStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          print(snapshot.stackTrace);
        }
        // ...
      }
);
```